# Python CSV DictReader issue with fields with commas inside

Tags: python, csv

I m trying to parse a CSV file with headers using **DictReader**. There happen to be some field values with commas inside them. Those commas shouldn't be used as delimiters. Only commas outside the quotes should be used as delimiters. 
Please let me know, how can I achieve this.

Let's assume, CSV file is like this:

```
field1, field2
"sdsad,asdsa","asdasd"
```

Answer (score 0):

the data in my example csv file is this

```
               field1, field2, field3
               "2012,A,", "F","1"
               "2013,B,", "M","2"
               "2014,C,", "M","3"
               "2015,D,", "M","4"
```

I used this code

```
                with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
                    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=("field1", "field2", "field3"), restkey=None, restval=None, dialect='excel')
                    for row in reader:
                        print(row['field1'],row['field2'],row['field3'])
```

The following is the output I got.

```
           ('field1', ' field2', ' field3')
           ('2012,A,', ' "F"', '1')
           ('2013,B,', ' "M"', '2')
           ('2014,C,', ' "M"', '3')
           ('2015,D,', ' "M"', '4')
```

You can also set the parameters such as **Dialect.delimiter** by creating an instance of Dialect class ( as suggested by the documentation) and then you can assign it to the **dialect** argument.

reference:- https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader